# Visual studio remote debugging: "unable to start debugging. the connection with the remote endpoint was terminated"

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

The connection is terminated after starting the debug, it is not running.
I'm using VS2013, 
The remote debugging monitor is running on the remote computer.
it is written:
"Msvsmon started a new server named 'ComputerName:4018'. Waiting for new connections."

I have succeeded connecting with remote desktop connection to the remote computer.

What kind of other checks can I perform to find a solution?

What could cause the connection to terminate?

**Update:** I can connect to the debug by tools->attach to process, though still can't succeed in debugging when running from remote windows debug.

Thanks

Comment: it was probably a problem with our network security configurations